# Stabilizer of doubly transitive group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I am reading about doubly transitive group actions. I am trying to prove that if $G$ acts doubly transitively on $X$, then $G_x$ is maximal for all $x\in X$ ($G_x$ is the stabilizer of $x$).

A part of the argument goes like this: Let $G_x\subsetneq H\subsetneq G$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$. Let $Y=\lbrace hx \text{ }\mid\text{ }h\in H\rbrace$. Then $Y\neq X$.

My question is why $Y\neq X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $g\in G\setminus H$. Then $gx\notin Y$. Indeed suppose $gx=hx$ for some $h\in H$. Then $h^{-1}gx=x$, so $h^{-1}g\in G_x\subseteq H$, so $g=h(h^{-1}g)\in H$, a contradiction.

Comment: So in general, we can conclude this (regardless of whether or not $G$ acts doubly transitively on $X$):
If $G_x\subseteq H\subsetneq G$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$, then
$Hx\subsetneq Gx$.

Comment: Yes. Maybe the best way to understand this is that there is a bijection $G/G_x\rightarrow Gx$ under which $H/G_x$ corresponds to $Hx$, so (assuming $G_x\subseteq H\subseteq G$), $H=G$ iff $H/G_x=G/G_x$ iff $Hx=Gx$.